# Create a Modal in front of every component in React Native

Tags: react-native, popup, simplemodal

I want to make the Modal to appear in front of all other components.
The root will be App.js, which create a router inside by using react-navigation, which contains a tab named Book.js.
In the Book.js, it will display a list of BookItem.js
What I want is when I click for every BookItem, a modal will display and cover everything including the router's bottomtabbar, but using the code I provided, which modalVisible = false, it will show the followings:

https://ibb.co/mSJ48FQ

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Router />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Router.js

```
export default createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator);
```

Books.js

```
    const createBookList = (data) => {
        setBooklist(data.datas.map(item => (
            <BookItem key={item.bid} data={item} />
        )))

    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.search}>
            <ScrollView>
                {booklist}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
```

Bookitem.js

```
    return (
        <View>
            <Modal isVisible={modalVisible}>
                <View>
                    <Text>Modal</Text>
                    <Button title="Hide modal" onPress={() => { setmModalVisible(false) }} />
                </View>
            </Modal>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setmModalVisible(true) }}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    { bookdetail }
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

Comment: Use only a Modal, and render it bellow ScrollView, and pass row data to Modal when list item is clicked.

Comment: So what you mean is that I just put the modal in a upper level and pass the data to it from child to parent?

Answer (score 0):

You could use react navigation modal screen.

RN Modal Reference:  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/modal.html

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually I have seen this post before I post this question. I am not sure how can I code it, as the structure of it is different from mine, my modal is opened in the component of one screen